# how to uninstall Kdenlive?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I have install Kdenlive, now I feel I don't need it do and so I want to uninstall it.

Normally i use to uninstall from lens. I used to right click on application and then uninstall it.

This time it does not show uninstall option. How to uninstall it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either the **Ubuntu Software Center**

[image]

[image]

Or via the terminal remove it with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdenlive
```

If you don't even want the config files to stay (Absolutely eliminate everything related to kdenlive) then use purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge kdenlive
```

I also recommend adding the Software Center icon to the launcher, since I do not see it in there on your image and it comes by default. This is for cases like the one you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command to remove `kdenlive` completely.

`sudo apt-get purge kdenlive`

It will remove `kdenlive` with all its configurations

Comment: This worked for me